# Recoding a function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have found this function which disables the skrollr javascript on mobile devices. It was not written for Wordpress, but I want to put it in my functions.php

```
$(function () {
// initialize skrollr if the window width is large enough
if ($(window).width() > 767) {
skrollr.init(yourOptions);
}

// disable skrollr if the window is resized below 768px wide
$(window).on('resize', function () {
if ($(window).width() <= 767) {
  skrollr.init().destroy(); // skrollr.init() returns the singleton created above
}
});
});
```

I'm new at programming so I don't know where it is supposed to be implemented to work

For those not familiar with skrollr, the html to provide effects on divs is ex.

```
<div class="container-fluid" data-75="opacity: 1;" data-250="opacity: 0;"
```

...

Comment: you can write this code in a js file and include in wordpress using wp_enqueue_script

Answer (score 2):

You *shouldn't* put this in **functions.php**. It's not PHP code...It's JavaScript.

Instead, you should add it to an external JavaScript file and properly [enqueue it](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) in **functions.php**.

Keep in mind that, unless you have loaded your own version of jQuery that isn't using "no-conflict" mode, you'll also need to modify the script slightly to make the `$` variable available to you like so:

```
(function($){
    // Your jQuery
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I've tried putting it in a javascript file and enquired it but it doesn't work (the skrollr effect works when mobile size) I added it to the skrollr.js file itself. When I add it to the bottom after the other scripts it does nothing, when I added it above the other scripts it removes skrollr on all screen sizes